# Macro Excel: To insert a text into a perfect square cell within a circle shape

Tags: vba, excel

How do I insert text into each cell (only perfect square cell) automatically or if there's any other ways? The label text are 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 2A, 2B, 2C, 2D and so on until the end of perfect square cell within the circle. The problem is, the cell has different width and height for each wafer die. The range for the row and column within the circle would be different too. My question is how do I label the circle automatically or other ways that's possible with the different height and width of the cells.

Here I attach what my wafer die would look like:

[image: Example of the wafer die]

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's suppose that our middle of a circle is located in cell `E5` (in left top corner, as shown in your picture). If we want determine if certain cell is within the circle we have to do the following. For example, let's check if cell C3 will be included. Let's assume that the radius of circle is `r`. So, now we need to calculate the distance between top left corner of E5 end bottom right of C3. So you need to calculate the height between the top of E5 and bottom of C3, in this case it will be height of 4th row (more generally, it will be the sume of heights of all rows between), let's call it `a`. Then, in similair manner, you calculate distance between left side of E column and right side of C column, so it will the width of D column (more generally, it will be the sum of widths of columns between), let's call it `b`. Then you use pitgeorean theorem to calculatte distance between corners: sqrt(a^2 + b^2). If it's less than `r` then cell is within the circle. If you want to determine if the whole cell is within the circle, you must additionally calculate the distance to top right corner of C3.

I think it gave a grasp on a problem and you are able to generalise it :)

Comment: I don't really get it. Can you show me based on VBA coding? Maybe it will be easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is a mathematical problem, before you can perform any labeling action (this will be the very last step), you need to calculate which cells are within the circle.

Therefore you need to check **each** cell (loop through) if it is within the circle.
A cell **is** within the circle if …

- The distance between any of the 4 vertexes (corners) of that cell and the center of the circle is less than the radius of the circle:
  **(x - center_x)<sup>2</sup> + (y - center_y)<sup>2</sup> < radius<sup>2</sup>**
  where `x` and `y` are the coordinates of one vertex and `center_x` and `center_y` are the coordinates of the circle center. This has to be checked for all 4 vertexes of the cell.
- You have to think about if the vertexes have to be …

  - within the circle (formula above)
  - or if a vertex laying exactly on the circle is still ok.
    **(x - center_x)<sup>2</sup> + (y - center_y)<sup>2</sup> <= radius<sup>2</sup>**

Now that you have checked all the cells and found out which are within the circle you can start labeling them by looping through the found cells.